# ggplotly: R, labeling trace names but keep one line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, kernel-density

I'm creating a ggplotly for a dataframe that's very similar to `diamonds`. Here's what I have so far:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, colour = cut)) +
geom_density() +
xlim(55, 70))
```

It creates the following:

[image]

When you hover over the trace it shows: depth, cut, and density. I want to also show the clarity so I added the following:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity), colour = cut)) +
 geom_density() +
 xlim(55, 70))
```

That command creates the following: [image: ggplot]

When I hover of the curve it shows depth, Clarity, cut, and density. That's what I want. However, how do I keep the density as one curve like how it was in the first plot I created instead of multiple curves?

Comment: Try without `aes` for text but you will have to write `diamonds$clarity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? Set the alpha of the extra lines to 0 (so they become transparent. Using geom_line as geom_density uses alpha for fill only. (system problems prevent testing)

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, colour = cut)) +
    geom_density() +
    geom_line(aes(text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity)), stat="density", alpha=0) + 
    xlim(55, 70)
)
```

Comment: It didn't work. it's shows one kernel density line for each cut but it's only displays three trace names: depth, cut, and density. NA removed the extra lines but if I hover over where they used to be it shows four trace names: depth, cut, Clarity, and density.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old answer, but the main problem here is that you're trying to do something that's logically impossible.

`clarity` and `cut` are two separate dimensions, so you can't simply put the `clarity` in a tooltip on the line that's grouped by `cut`, because that line represents diamonds of all different `clarity`s grouped together.

Once you add `clarity` into the mix (via the `text` aesthetic), ggplot rightly separates the various `clarities` out, so that it has a `clarity` to refer to.  You could force it back to grouping just by `cut` by adding `group=cut` to the `aes`, but you'll lose the `clarity` tooltip, because there's no meaningful value of `clarity` when you're grouping just by `cut` - again, each point is all clarities at once.

Richard's solution simply displays both graphs at once, but makes the `clarity`-grouped ones invisible.  I'm not sure what the original goal was here, but that doesn't accomplish anything useful, because it just lets you mouse-over invisible peaks in addition to the properly-grouped `cut` bands.

I'm not sure what your original data was, but you simply can't display two dimensions and group by only one of them.  You'd either have to use the multiple curves, which accurately represent the second dimension, or flatten the second dimension by doing some sort of summarization of it - in the case of `clarity`, there's not really any sensible summarization you can do, but if it were, say, price, you could display an average.